# Spark structured streaming truncates Kafka value string to 4095

Tags: string, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming, truncate

The following code

```
builder = SparkSession.builder\
   .appName("PythonTest11")
spark = builder.getOrCreate()

#spark.conf.set("spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields", 10000)

# Subscribe to 1 topic
df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", config["kafka"]["bootstrap.servers"]) \
  .option("subscribe", dataFlowTopic) \
  .load()

df = df \
    .selectExpr("LENGTH(value)")
#.selectExpr("CAST(value as string)") \


df.printSchema()

# Start running the query that prints the running counts to the console
query = df \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode('append') \
    .format('console') \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

prints

```
+-------------+
|length(value)|
+-------------+
|         4095|
+-------------+
```

for any big message, i.e. it truncates incoming strings.

How to fix this?

Comment: You're selecting the length of a byte array, not a string. Perhaps you wanted `LENGTH(CAST(value as string))`?

Comment: Other than that, Kafka itself imposes a default max allowable message size, but you'd see that error on the broker/producer before it would arrive at Spark

Answer (score 1):

It was something like console truncation or something. Not Kafka or Spark problem.

First I was running

```
# kafka-console-producer.sh --topic dataflow --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

and then pasting messages to it's command line and truncation was occurring.

The I ran

```
# kafka-console-producer.sh --topic dataflow --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 < row01.json
```

with the same data inside `row01.json` and it worked without truncation.